# Power apps Custom Connector using Azure active directory OAuth

Tags: powerapps, power-platform, power-automate-custom-connector, power-apps-custom-connector

I have a requirement to create a power apps custom connector which uses Azure Active Directory authentication and implements On behalf of user flow. The custom connnector needs to talk to a protected api allowing the user to login using their AAD credentials.

I have added the connector and set the following inputs

Authorization URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Token Endpoint : https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token

Clientid : SPN which has been granted access to the API scope

Secret : Secret of the SPN

Tenant ID : xxxxxxxxx

Resource URl : api://[ApI client id]

Scope : api://[API client id]/.default
[image]
Problems:

1. I cannot set the "Enable on-behalf-of login" to true. Whatever I do, it comes back to false after saving.
2. Note that after saving, the tenant ID becomes common. Not sure why.
3. When I test the connector using my credentials, it gives error with Authentication failed. Testing the API using Swagger works just fine.

Any idea how to properly create the connector using AAD? I would like to use the connector in power apps agent and impersonate the end user.